# Textarea filling remaing width

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` containing an `<img>` and a `<textarea>` like this:

```
<div style="width: 50%">
 <img />
 <textarea>...</textarea>
</div>
```

`<img>` has variable width. How to make the textarea fillup the remaing space?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try set a percentage width for the image and another for the text area.

Comment: Yes but setting a percentage width to the image will deform the image...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell` and help achieve this like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="containerRow">
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <img href="[your_image_address]" alt="[your_image_alt]" />
        </div>
        <div class="textareaContainer">
            <textarea>[your_textarea_content]</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.containerRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.imageContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1px;
}
.textareaContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.textareaContainer textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BA82E/)**

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the parents and children that are supposed to fill up the space use `width:100%`, which is relative to their parent container. So the `<textarea>` need to be defined as having 100% width, along with the image. Likewise they would need to be defined as `display:inline` or `inline-block` versus `block` so that they appear next to each other. Another option is to use a CSS table as: `<div>` with `display:table`, `<div>` with `display:table-row` and then `<span>` with `display: table-cell` for the columns that have the `<image>` and `<textarea>`; respectively. That will fit those elements into a CSS table that if defined as width:100% will fill up its parent.

Comment: This answer is correct as proven via this link. I need to try out jsfiddle to demo things so show things like this more concretely.